# Conceptual: how to code battleships between two computers in Python?

Tags: python, p2p

this is a conceptual question. As part hobby, part art project I'm looking to build a Python script that allows two people to play battleships between their computers (across the net, without being on the same network).

The idea would be you could run the program something like:

python battleships.py 192.168.1.1

Where the IP address would be the computer you wanted to do battle with.

I have some modest Python coding abilities but I'm curious how hard it would be to build this and how one might go about it?

One key goal is that it must require almost zero set-up: I'm hoping anyone can download the python script, open the terminal and play battleships with someone else.

Thanks!

Comment: I rough Google pulled out this gist: https://gist.github.com/jsam/4185756
It should have enough of a working example to demonstrate client/server communication; further than that I think you're pretty on your own for writing the Battleship front end.

Answer (score -1):

I think the simpliest way to do this is reading socket server in this battleship game. But here is a problem, in this case you will have a problem with connecting, in case when your ip is invisible from the internet.